# How to open url of windows app on IE browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please guide me. . .

I am using TwinTool by using Selenium & generate test-code plan to open my desktop app url on IE browser. I have chosen TwinTool for UI window based application.

I am uptodate with TwinJar as external jars in Eclipse.

Comment: Could you please add what you've tried and what problems you've had?

Comment: "desktop app URL on IE browser".  What does that mean?  It's a desktop app? or a browser app?  Do you mean a localhost application?  Please provide more details such as what URL you use?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why have you chosen [TWIN](https://code.google.com/archive/p/twin/) (developed by eBay) to test an IE browser. My answer will hopefully convince you to research other tools.

There are some reasons why you will not get help with working with TWIN.

1. I has not been under development since 2011.
2. This means that probably no one is using it.
3. It was designed to drive desktop applications, not browsers like IE, since these are already supported by Selenium itself.
4. Looks like TWIN is badly documented.

I would advice to search for an alternative, maybe just Selenium if only you want to test with IE.

Next to that wonder if you really need to test IE, maybe Edge, Firefox or Chrome is good enough. Read: https://watirmelon.blog/2014/03/13/do-you-really-need-to-run-your-webdriver-tests-in-ie/

Maybe this guide can help you with setting up Selenium and IE. Read: http://learn-automation.com/execute-selenium-script-in-ie-browser/

Comment: I choose AUTOIT instead TWIN , guys